# Member of object ignored

Tags: javascript, json

first of all I am very bad at web programming, and i have a problem... Here is my index.js: https://pastebin.com/92SGEChN, my postBook() function:

```
function postBook() {
   
    let bookTitle = document.getElementById("b-title").value;

    let bookAuthor = document.getElementById("b-author").value;
    let bookDesc = document.getElementById("b-descript").value;
 
    const book = {
        title: bookTitle,
        author: bookAuthor,
        description: bookDesc
    };

    /// il postez
    fetch('/books', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(book)
    }).then(function() {
        getBooks();
    });
}
```

and here is my script.js: https://pastebin.com/S7e2vYrc.

```
app.post("/books", (req, res) => {
  const booksList = readJSONFile();
  var newId = uuidv1();
  var newBook =
  {
    title: req.body.title,
    author: req.body.author,
    description: req.body.description,
    id: newId
  };
  booksList.push(newBook);
  writeJSONFile(booksList);
  res.send(booksList);
});
```

Seems like "author" member of the book object is never seen, and it does not appear in db.json . Why, and how can I solve this ?

Comment: Do some basic debugging. In the browser, inspect the XHR in the dev tools (F12). On the server-side, add `console.log(req.body);`

Comment: What do you see in the Chrome console when you `console.log(bookAuthor)` before the submission?

Comment: After your `fetch(/* args */)` should be like: `.then(response=>response.json())
 .then(data=>{ /* do stuff with data */});`. You're not doing anything with the data.

Comment: @StackSlave it was working perfectly before adding "author" to book object, when it was only id, title and description. In my html when I print author it says "undefined".